# How do I locate or get parent of child in tree

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tree

I am making a tree from a text file like this:

```
Store, manager, employee
manager, smith, Michael
employee, steve, karen, litt, kwan
```

my code is something like this:

```
reads first line;
sets first string to parent and following to children
reads second line, sets first string to parent and following to children
```

But I want to read the second line, see if the first string is children in above string, and assign the value the first string(parent of second line) to that children to achieve a tree structure like this:

```
        Store
          /
    manager - employee
      /              \
  smith - Michael     steve - karen - litt - kwan
```

I cannot figure out the part where I check if the parent of the string is a child of any previous string and set it to that child

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashMap.
Suppose you have a Node class like this:

```
class Node{
   String value;
   Node parent;
   Node[] children;
}
```

When you construct you tree,You can construct a `HashMap<String,Node>` to map the string value to the Node Object.

Then you can check `map.get(stringValue)==null` to see if the stringValue is a child of above String.